# Asterisk + Starpy : Failed to originate call

Tags: python, asterisk, asteriskami

I'm using Starpy to automate Asterisk. Everything works except sometimes I get one call out of 150 where Asterisk fails to originate call.

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/starpy/manager.py", line 154, in    lineReceived
    self.dispatchIncoming()  # does dispatch and clears cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/starpy/manager.py", line 242, in dispatchIncoming
callback(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 362, in callback
self._startRunCallbacks(result)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 458, in _startRunCallbacks
   self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 545, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/starpy/manager.py", line 348, in errorUnlessResponse
raise error.AMICommandFailure(message)
starpy.error.AMICommandFailure: {'message': 'Originate failed', 'response': 'Error', 'actionid': '53345672-2'}
```

Based on my research, this error occurs when the callee does not answer the call. However, I'm not convinced and looking for more details about why "origiate failed". I thought about monitoring the channel before we start dialing, but it doesn't work. Channel monitor needs to be called after the callee answers the call.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use tcpdump or other similar tool to see what exactly asterisk sends

After that fix that library, very likly it just have bug.

Comment: No, StarPY doesn't have a bug in it (at least not in Originating channels. You may get 1.4 syntax for variables passed in an AMI command depending on what repo you get it from). We use StarPY in the Asterisk Test Suite, and it makes thousands of "calls" a day.

An Originate failure is typically due to the channel not getting answered. You can handle this by setting an errBack on the deferred returned by the function call to originate.

Comment: ah, okay.so you call that "feature". anyway it is in lib, not in asterisk. so have be addressed to lib mailing list.

Comment: Your sarcastic use of quotes not withstanding, the fact that the channel was not answered is considered an error condition. You need an indication that the channel wasn't answered, and the error condition provides that. twisted easily lets you handle errors in callback handlers. I don't see why you would want different behavior.